# Establishing Connection with Oracle Database 11g XE in Xamarin

Tags: c#, oracle, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oracle11gr2

I'm very new to C# and Xamarin development, so I apologize if there is a simple answer to this problem. I have been unable to find one so far. I am currently using Visual Studio 2017, newest version of Xamarin, and Windows 7 Professional operating system.

I've been working on this issue for a week now and with no real progress being made. I've done a plethora of research and attempted a multitude of different solutions, all with the same result. I'm unable to establish an OracleConnection in my application without getting several compile-time errors.

List of things I've tried:

-Download Oracle.ManagedDataAccess NuGet package. This results in several incompatibility errors with Xamarin libraries (ios, monoandroid81, etc.). I've updated everything, so I don't know the problem there.

-Use ODAC for Visual Studio 2017. Works to establish a connection from Visual Studio to the database, but I can't access the database within the application code itself.

-Use Oracle.DataAccess.dll found in server files. Works up until I build the application, at which point System.x files are not loaded properly. I then add the System.x.dll from Microsoft.NET folder, and the error pops up again with a different System.x file.

-Use Oracle.DataAccess.dll from any other location. Same as above.

I may have forgotten a few things I've tried(probably lost during the time spent smashing my against the wall).

Any assistance with this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Directly accessing Oracle (or any SQL database) via a mobile's data connection is a bad idea in general... Oracle has `ORDS` which provides a REST API, while they have many white papers on the subject, they have quick overview blog post : https://blogs.oracle.com/newgendbaccess/why-use-rest

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks, I'll look into it right now!